# unresolved external can't link to visa32.lib instrument control library

Tags: c++builder

I'm writing a test equipment control program in C++Builder 10.4 using the `visa32.lib` (or visa54) supplied by the instrument company.  I have some calls included, as per their examples, and the program compiles fine with the `visa.h` header included.

However, I get unresolved external errors on all the calls in my program.  I put the recommended directories in the library path in the "C++ Shared options" area:

C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\lib\bc
C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\lib\msc

I've also tried putting in the `visa64.lib` for a 64-bit program in the Lib path for 64-bit compiles. It compiles fine, but same link errors.

Here's a snippet of the calls, from instrument company examples:

```cpp
ViSession defaultRM, vi;
char buf [256] = {0};
String s,strTemp;
char* stringTemp;
ViChar buffer [VI_FIND_BUFLEN];
ViRsrc matches=buffer;
ViUInt32 nmatches;
ViFindList list;

viOpenDefaultRM (&defaultRM);

//Acquire the USB resource of VISA
viFindRsrc(defaultRM, "USB?*", &list,&nmatches, matches);
viOpen (defaultRM,matches,VI_NULL,VI_NULL,&vi);
```

---

EDIT UPDATE: I added this line to my code:

```cpp
#pragma comment(lib, "C:\Program Files (x86)\\IVI Foundation\\VISA\\WinNT\\lib\\msc\\visa32.lib")
```

And that seems to have gotten me past the unresoloved externals, but I now get this new error (This is for a 32-bit compile):

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\IVI FOUNDATION\VISA\WINNT\LIB\MSC\VISA32.LIB' contains invalid OMF record, type 0x21 (possibly COFF)
```

Comment: You have to add the *.lib file (picking the correct one for 32 bit or 64 bit) to the project. (ie add it in the same way that you add your *.cpp files)

Comment: Since this is C++, sometimes different compilers or compiler versions have different 'name mangling' schemes = how they generate symbol names to cope with different overloads, class function properties, etc. You may need to use the same compiler as the library was built with. These often correspond to calling scheme variations i.e. you can't just rename the symbols to match to get this to work.

Comment: Roger-OK, that worked as far as it finding the library.  So I did that and removed the #pragma that I added per my edit, the end result is the same however with a new error regarding the invalid OMF record.

Comment: Rup- Oh my, that's a big problem.  I use C++ builder for everything.  The examples given show how to use the library with MS Visual c++.  So apparently that library was created with that.  Wonder where to go from here?

Comment: Would using the IMPLIB or COFF2OMF tool help me here?

Answer (score 1):

The `.lib` file you are using is meant for Visual Studio, not C++Builder.  `.lib` files are compiler-specific, so you can't use MSVC libs in C++Builder, and vice versa.

If you have a DLL for the 3rd party library, you can use C++Builder's [IMPLIB](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/IMPLIB.EXE,_the_Import_Library_Tool_for_Win32) (32-bit) or [MKEXP](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/MKEXP.EXE,_the_64-bit_Windows_Import_Library_Tool_for_C%2B%2B) (64-bit) tool to create a new `.lib` file from the DLL, and then you can use that new `.lib` in C++Builder.

Otherwise, you will have to ask the vendor for a C++Builder-compatible `.lib` file, or else you will have to compile the `.lib` file into your own DLL with Visual Studio, and then use that DLL in C++Builder as above.

Comment: It turns out there are several DLLs supplied so I might be in luck here.  I'll give this a go and see what happens.  Thanks.

Comment: Really dumb question, but how do I invoke the command window to enter the implib command?  I followed the instructions about compiling and then going to the message area, but nothing opens up there.  Sorry, must be a silly question.

Comment: `IMPLIB` and `MKEXP` are console apps.  Use Windows' own Console window (Start | Run | cmd.exe) to execute them

Comment: Well, I'm batting a thousand today.  I can't figure out the syntax here:  If I put in this I get these errors:
C:\Users\ken>implib NiViUsb.lib C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Bin\NiViUsb.dll

Embarcadero Implib Version 3.4.0 Copyright (c) 1991-2016 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
Error C:\: unable to open file
Error : unable to open file
Error (x86)\: unable to open file
Error Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Bin\: unable to open file

Comment: @Buckethead paths with spaces in them must be wrapped in double-quotes, eg: `implib NiViUsb.lib "C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Bin\NiViUsb.dll"`

Comment: Just an update.  I'm happy to report that I am now reading and writing to my oscilloscope and function generator from C++ Builder after converting the visa32.dll to a lib using the implib and adding the new lib to to the project.  Had to figure a few things out like the fact that I needed to use a def file to list the actual calls I would be using in order to create a lib file with anything in it and that the command console doesn't like spaces in file names, :) but was overjoyed when my scope actually responded to a button press.  Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: @Buckethead you shouldn't need to use a def file, since implib will look at the DLL's actual exports and create a lib with symbols that refer to them. You would need a def file only if you want to customize how those symbols are named